# Streaming metrics for Flink application

Tags: user-interface, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I have set up Flink UI for application running in Intellij IDEA. I would like to get some streaming metrics like - scheduling delay and processing time. However, I can not find the anywhere in UI. Should there be some specific setup for that or should I explicitly submit app jar?

Currently, Flink UI for the job looks like this:

[image: st]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of the task metrics are exposed in the web UI, as Dominik mentioned, but for other metric scopes (e.g., job metrics) only some selected metrics are displayed. You can access all of the metrics via the [REST API](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/monitoring/rest_api.html) or by connecting a [metrics reporter](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/monitoring/metrics.html#reporter) to send the metrics to an external metrics system.

I don't think any attempt has been to made to measure scheduling delay, but in the job metrics you will find things like [restarting time and uptime](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/monitoring/metrics.html#availability).

Answer (score 0):

In the UI you should have a tab `Task Metrics` when You select the currently running job. This tab allows You to choose a task and see all the metrics that are available. Although, I am not sure if the scheduling delay is one of currently available metrics.

Probably the better idea is to refer to expose the metrics for some collector of Your choice, You can find more info in the documentation: https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/monitoring/metrics.html.